# Does igraph's gomory_hu_tree calculate the minimum cut tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree, igraph

I'm trying to implement [this graph clustering algorithm (sec. 3.2)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.im/1109191029) with python-igraph. As I do not want to calculate the minimum cut tree myself, I'm trying to use the `gomory_hu_tree()` method. To play around with this method (and to provide a MWE), I wrote the following:

```
from igraph import *

g= Graph()

g.add_vertices(4)

g.vs["name"] = ["0", "1", "2", "artificial"]

g.add_edge("0", "1", weight=10.0)
g.add_edge("0", "2", weight=20.0)
g.add_edge("2", "1", weight=30.0)
g.add_edge("artificial", "0", weight=100.0)
g.add_edge("artificial", "1", weight=100.0)
g.add_edge("artificial", "2", weight=100.0)

t = g.gomory_hu_tree(capacity="weight")
print t.es["flow"]
print
print t
```

I get the following output:

```
[130.0, 140.0, 150.0]

IGRAPH UNW- 4 3 --
+ attr: name (v), flow (e), weight (e)
+ edges (vertex names):
0--1, 1--2, 2--artificial
```

But that is not a minimum cut tree! If the tree were like this, then the removal of the edge between `1` and `2` would yield a partition of the graph into the two subsets `{0, 1}` and `{2, t}` at a cost of 250. However, the right answer is a cut into `{1}` and `{2, 0, t}` at a cost of just 140.

(By "cost" I mean the value of the respective cut.)

So, one (and the only) right answer for the min cut tree would have been

```
0--artificial, 1--artificial, 2--artificial
```

What did I get wrong? Is it possibly wrong to use the `gomory_hu_tree()` method in this context?

*Note:* I originally [asked this question in a completely wrong way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297470/igraphs-gomory-hu-tree-not-working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of definitions:

1)A tree is called a **flow equivalent tree** if and only if for each pair of nodes (u, v) maximal flow between these two nodes in a tree is the same as in the original graph(and this implies that the cost of the minimum cut is the same).

2)A tree satisfies a **cut property** if and only if for each pair of nodes (u, v) the minimum cut in this tree is the same as in the original graph(not just the cost is the same, but two subsets are the same too).

So the question is: What is A Gomory-Hu tree? There are two common definitions:
1)A flow equivalent tree.
2)A flow equivalent tree that satisfies cut property.

Even though it is not documented what definition is used in this library, it seems that they used the first one. So it is only guaranteed that the cost of the cut is the same, not the cut itself. If you need to find the cut itself, you can use `maxflow` method for a fixed pair of nodes.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure whether, given a mere flow equivalent tree, I can turn it into one with the cut property, i.e. the kind of min cut tree I'm looking for. It is not at all clear to me if having a flow equivalent tree makes the task of finding one with the cut property easier. Is there any python graph library (I tried graph-tool, NetworkX) that has something appropriate?

Comment: I have never heard of an easy way to turn a flow equivalent tree into a true min cut tree(I would say it would be easier to build it properly from scratch because it is a well-known algorithm). I don't have much experience in working with python graph libraries so I don't know if there is a library with a proper mincut tree.