# Why is the Hu-Gomory from Networkx is not minimal communication tree or uniuqe?

Tags: python, graph, tree, networkx

I downloaded the Networkx libary and used it in order to find Hu-Gomory tree.

I created the following simple graph

```
weight_edge_lst = []
weight_edge_lst.append((0,1,0))
weight_edge_lst.append((1,2,1))
weight_edge_lst.append((0,2,1))
G.add_weighted_edges_from(weight_edge_lst)
```

It plotted this tree:

[(0, 1), (1, 2)]

This is weird, because in articles it has been written that Cut-tree is optimal communication tree, which means that sum of edges (cut) capacity is minimal, and the tree of (1,2),(0,2) would have sum of 2 and not 3 as this tree.

If i change the order of edges this way -

weight_edge_lst.append((0,1,1))

weight_edge_lst.append((1,2,1))

weight_edge_lst.append((0,2,0))

It works, and edges of the tree are on the one-capacity edges, but this is the exact same graph (with changes in names!)

Does anyone has any explanation for that ?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you mean by a sum of "3 as this tree"?

Comment: And does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297470/igraphs-gomory-hu-tree-not-working

Comment: We try to compute a spanning tree of the graph, when each edge represents a cut (between the nodes that this edge separates in the tree). the "target function" we want to minimize is the sum of those "cuts" capacities (each edge refer to a cut).

Comment: So the answer to the question I linked to seems to address your question.  Does it?  If not, I can try to help, but I still don't understand what is meant by a sum of 3.